# Deploying laravel application or making it live on Github pages

Tags: php, git, github, laravel-5, github-pages

I have one laravel application named Photogallery. And I wanted to make it live on github pages .

Since I dont know how to do it plese help me here.

Comment: Github pages is static markup and doesn't to my knowledge support PHP. You will need your own hosting provider and a valid domain name pointed to your hosting provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Github pages only allow static html. To do so you need to upload your static site with all the resources (css, javascript, images,...) to the Github pages branch.

Answer (score 3):

1. The GitHub Pages do not support PHP and thus cannot run a Laravel
   application.
2. GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service that takes HTML, CSS,
   and JavaScript files straight from a repository on GitHub,
   optionally runs the files through a build process and publishes a
   website.
3. Github Pages uses Jekyll to build static HTML files and serve those.